# Output Text to speech to microphone

Tags: c#, speech-synthesis, linden-scripting-language

I am having a chatterbot using the Alice libraries, which I am now trying to get Text to Speech to work on.
The thing is though, I do not want the speach to go through the speakers, but instead, used as if it was a microphone to bradcast it on a SIP channel.

It may sound nutty, but it's thought to be used in a game environment (secondlife), where users can communicate through both text and speech.
The problem is that the voice libraries seems only to allow for microphones.

Is this at all possble?

Answer (score 2):

Try a software driver such as Virtual Audio Cable. Route the output of the text-to-speech app to VAC, and have the Second Life viewer use VAC as its audio source. 
http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm

On OS X, Livestream has a gizmo that will accomplish the same thing. That can even be used for routing Second Life audio output to OS X QuickTime's inout when making screen movies.